# How to profile Next.js app using unminified function names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

#### Summary

I am trying to **profile the performance** of my website.  In order to more easily read the performance traces, I'd like to **use unminified versions** of both my app code and the **Next.js framework code**.

✅ I was able to disable minification in my app code by setting `config.webpack.optimization.minimize` to false.

❌ **Disabling minification in the framework code** has been more complicated.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. cloned [next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js)
2. followed [Developing](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/contributing/core/developing.md) to get Next running locally
3. Checked out `v12.3.4` which is the version my website uses
4. `pnpm dev`
5. followed [Developing Using Your Local Version of Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/contributing/core/developing-using-local-app.md#developing-using-your-local-version-of-nextjs)

Expected:
Should show unminified function names

Actual:
Website works, but still uses minified code.  I can see that in `dist/apps/journey/app/.next/static/chunks/framework-0e49fded8df17ef1.js` it is still minifying function names.

I can see in the Next repo that it's not being minified, so the minification must be happening in my app even though I disabled minification.  Would someone please help me **link Next without minifying the code** (or at least function/variable names)?  Alternatively, **showing source maps for the Next/React internals** would be great. Ideally I'd like to not minify Next/React (to make debugging easier), but sourcemaps would be fine.

#### Additional information

Next.js version: **12.3.4**

```js
❯ pnpm next info

    Operating System:
      Platform: linux
      Arch: x64
      Version: #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.10.0
      npm: 7.24.0
      Yarn: 1.22.19
      pnpm: 7.25.0
    Relevant packages:
      next: 12.3.4
      eslint-config-next: 12.1.5
      react: 17.0.2
      react-dom: 17.0.2

warn  - Latest canary version not detected, detected: "12.3.4", newest: "13.5.7-canary.17".
        Please try the latest canary version (`npm install next@canary`) to confirm the issue still exists before creating a new issue.
        Read more - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opening-an-issue
```

Please see [related GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/57292) if anybody has responded there.